# cublasDtrsm after LU with pivoting

Tags: cuda, lapack, cublas

I am stuck at a small problem. I've got to solve a linear System `A * x = b`.

The matrix `A` gets decomposed by an LU-factorization (`LAPACK`). As result I get the factorized Matrix and the pivotarray. After that I want to solve the two linear Systems: `U * x = y` and `L * y = b` on the GPU with `*cublasDtrsm*`. But because of the row interchanges from `dgetrf` in `LAPACK` I would have to pass the pivot array to `cublas`. But the `*cublasDtrsm*`-function don't offers something for this. Without the pivot array I get wrong results.

I already searched for disabling pivoting in `LAPACK`, but regarding to stability it's not possible. Is there any hint how to solve a linear Equation system with LU-factorization?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to get the correct result if you rearrange the elements of your RHS vectors in the same order that the LAPACK  `getrf` pivoting swapped rows of the original `A` matrix. I think it should be possible to infer this order-of-rearrangement from the pivot array (`ipiv`) returned by LAPACK `getrf`.  I believe this can be done in a simple fashion using the row interchange formula given in the [LAPACK getrf documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d7f/_v_a_r_i_a_n_t_s_2lu_2_c_r_2dgetrf_8f.html) for `ipiv`.  Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: Thank you.

I thought about it yes, but i guessed there would be something in `cuBLAS` to commit the pivotarray or in `LAPACK` to deactivate the pivoting. The first point isn't available even not in `CUDA` 7.0. And to deactivate it in `LAPACK` i would have to edit the source code. Because I'm not the only one using LU-decomposition and triangular solvers i hoped for a faster way, for example an existing function in `LAPACK`or `cuBLAS`.

Comment: I believe the pivoting is central to algorithm stability.  You wouldn't want to deactivate it, I don't think.

Comment: Normally yes. But we have normalized Matrices, where the values don't differ to much. So it's not so important and negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use this particular approach (cublas trsm after LAPACK getrf), I believe you should be able to use cublas trsm with the L,U output of LAPACK by rearranging your b vector (or matrix) to match the rearrangement order that LAPACK performed during pivoting.  I believe this order is given in the formula for `ipiv` in the [LAPACK documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d7f/_v_a_r_i_a_n_t_s_2lu_2_c_r_2dgetrf_8f.html):

> IPIV
>             IPIV is INTEGER array, dimension (min(M,N))
>             The pivot indices; for 1 <= i <= min(M,N), row i of the
>             matrix was interchanged with row IPIV(i).

Here's a sample code that demonstrates the idea for a simple 3x3 test case with a single RHS vector:

```
$ cat t853.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#define cudacall(call)                                                                                                          \
    do                                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                                           \
        cudaError_t err = (call);                                                                                               \
        if(cudaSuccess != err)                                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nReason = %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err));    \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                                       \
    }                                                                                                                           \
    while (0)

#define cublascall(call)                                                                                        \
    do                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                           \
        cublasStatus_t status = (call);                                                                         \
        if(CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != status)                                                                     \
        {                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUBLAS Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nCode = %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, status);     \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                       \
                                                                                                                \
    }                                                                                                           \
    while(0)


void LU_device(float *src_d, int n, int *pivot)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublascall(cublasCreate_v2(&handle));

    int batchSize = 1;

    int *P, *INFO;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&P,n * batchSize * sizeof(int)));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&INFO,batchSize * sizeof(int)));

    int lda = n;

    float *A[] = { src_d };
    float **A_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float*>(&A_d,sizeof(A)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(A_d,A,sizeof(A),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublascall(cublasSgetrfBatched(handle,n,A_d,lda,P,INFO,batchSize));

    int INFOh = 0;
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(&INFOh,INFO,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(pivot,P,n*batchSize*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
    for (int qq = 0; qq < n*batchSize; qq++) {printf("pivot[%d] = %d\n", qq, pivot[qq]); }
#endif

    if(INFOh == n)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Factorization Failed: Matrix is singular\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cudaFree(P); cudaFree(INFO); cudaFree(A_d); cublasDestroy(handle);
}

void LU(float* src, float* L, float *U, int n, int *pivot)
{
    float *src_d;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&src_d, n*n * sizeof(float)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(src_d,src,n*n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    LU_device(src_d,n,pivot);

    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(L,src_d,n * n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(U,src_d,n * n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)   L[i*n+j] = 0.0;
      for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) U[i*n+j] = 0.0;}

    cudaFree(src_d);
}

void rearrange(float *vec, int *pivot, int n, int dir){
#define DIR_FORWARD 0
#define DIR_REVERSE 1
#define SWAP(x,y) {float swaptmp=(*(y)); (*(y))=(*(x)); (*(x))=swaptmp;}
  if (dir == DIR_FORWARD)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    SWAP((vec+i),(vec+pivot[i]-1))
  else
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) SWAP((vec+i),(vec+pivot[i]-1))
}


void TRSM(float *A, float *x, float *b, int n, cublasFillMode_t uplo, cublasDiagType_t diagt ){

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublascall(cublasCreate_v2(&handle));
    float *A_d, *b_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&A_d, n*n * sizeof(float)));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&b_d, n * sizeof(float)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(b_d, b,   n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(A_d, A, n*n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    const float alpha = 1.0f;
    cublascall(cublasStrsm(handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, uplo, CUBLAS_OP_N, diagt, n, 1, &alpha, A_d, n, b_d, n));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(x, b_d, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaFree(A_d); cudaFree(b_d); cublasDestroy(handle);
}

void test_solve()
{
 // solve Ax=b
 // 1. Perform LU on A
 // 2. using pivot sequence, rearrange b -> b'
 // 3. perform TRSM on Ly=b'
 // 4. perform TRSM on Ux=y
 // A = |0 1  4 |
 //     |3 3  9 |
 //     |4 10 16|
 // x = |1|
 //     |2|
 //     |3|
 // b = |14|
 //     |36|
 //     |72|

    const int n = 3;

// has 3,2,3 pivot order
    float          A_col_major[n*n] = { 0, 3, 4,
                                        1, 3, 10,
                                        4, 9, 16 };
    float b1[n] = {14, 36, 72};
/* another example - has 3,3,3 pivot order
    float          A_transpose[n*n] = { 0, 1,  4,
                                        3, 3,  9,
                                        4, 10, 16 };
    float b2[n] = {18, 37, 70};
*/
    float result_x[n];
    int pivot[n];
    float L[n*n];
    float U[n*n];
    float y[n];

    //Select matrix by setting "a"
    float *a = A_col_major;
    float *b = b1;

    printf("Input:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%f\t",a[i*n+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
// 1. LU on A
    LU(a,L,U,n,pivot);
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
    printf("L:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%f\t",L[i*n+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("U:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%f\t",U[i*n+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");

#endif
// 2. Rearrange b
    rearrange(b,pivot,n,DIR_FORWARD);
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("b'[%d] = %f\n", i, b[i]);
#endif
// 3. TRSM on Ly=b
    TRSM(L, y, b, n, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT);
// 4. TRSM on Ux=y
    TRSM(U, result_x, y, n, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT);

    fprintf(stdout, "Solution:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            printf("%f\n",result_x[i]);
    }

}

int main()
{
    test_solve();

    return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t853 t853.cu -lcublas
$ ./t853
Input:

0.000000        3.000000        4.000000
1.000000        3.000000        10.000000
4.000000        9.000000        16.000000


Solution:

1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
$
```

Note that for this simple test case I used cublas getrfBatched to do the matrix LU factorization, rather than LAPACK, but I think it should behave similarly to LAPACK.

Also note that I'm not intending to comment on the "best approaches for linear system solutions" but merely to explain how the approach you mapped out might be made to work.

Comment: Thank you for the code. After a short look over it, it's the functionality i searched for. It's a little bit confusing, that the LU-Decomposition uses pivoting but the solver don't offers the commiting of the pivotarray

Answer (score 0):

For permutation on the GPU a permutation matrix can be created out of the given vector and multiplied it with `B` on the GPU. In fact the permutation vector from `LAPACK` is meant as an sequential order of swapping steps. So if the n-th line has been touched by the for-loop it will never be touched again. Hence a small Algorithm creates a permutation matrix `P` out of the vector from `*<T>getrf*`. With that the linear System `L * U * X = P * B` will be solved. This leads to the correct results.

```
void
permutationMatrix ( int const rows,      //number of rows of A
                    int const cols,      //number of cols of A
                    int* permArray,      //permutation vector from LAPACK
                    double* permMatrix)  //Memory for permutation matrix
{

    int tempPerm [rows];    //holds where the ones later shall be in the Matrix
    int swap;               //variable for swapping

    memset(permMatrix,0, rows * cols * sizeof(double)); //fill permutation Matrix with 0s
    memset(tempPerm,0, rows * sizeof(int)); //fill temporary memory with 0s

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++)  
    {
        //start value for each temp field is the row-number
        if (tempPerm [row] == 0)
        {
            tempPerm [row] = row + 1;
        }

        /* rows need to be swapped if rownumber != number 
         * in permutation vector of LAPACK*/
        if (permArray[row] != row + 1)
        {
            //swap with a line which hasn't already swapped
            if (tempPerm[permArray[row]-1] == 0)
            {
                tempPerm[permArray[row]-1] = tempPerm[row];
                tempPerm[row] = permArray[row];
            }else{

                //swap with an already touched line
                swap = tempPerm[permArray[row]-1];
                tempPerm[permArray[row]-1] = tempPerm[row];
                tempPerm[row] = swap;
            }
        }

        //put the one in place in the permutation matrix
        permMatrix[row + (tempPerm[row]-1) * rows] = 1.0;
    }
}
```